# Cross-domain window-to-window communication with easyXDM

Tags: javascript, easyxdm

I'm trying to use easyXDM to communication with a popup window on another domain than the parent. I have seen this example:
http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/bridge.html

However, this example has an intermediary page and frankly is extremely complicated. I can't figure out how to extrapolate this code to apply to my (possibly simpler?) situation.

Does anyone have an tips, tricks, articles that could help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the situation? Can you describe it more clearly so that we can figure out how to help you?

Comment: Domain A has a link that opens a login window that resides on domain B. After clicking login on domain B, the login process finishes, and reloads the window. Upon reloading the window I want to post a message back to the parent with the users information and for the popup window to be closed.